# «Такого унижения он не должен был потерпеть». Всё правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, лексическая-сочетаемость

Предложение прозвучало пару дней назад в передаче «60 минут».
*Такого унижения он не должен был потерпеть.*

Что-то "кольнуло" меня в этой конструкции, когда я ее услышала: то ли должен быть другой падеж (*такое унижение?*), то ли другой глагол (*терпеть?*).
Или все верно? Подскажите, развейте сомнения.

Comment: Такого унижения он не должен был стерпеть.

Comment: Ой, ладно, скучно очень.

Comment: Что это вы вдруг заскучали?

Comment: Ну мой ответ, видимо, настолько глупый, что никто не хочет его даже прокомментировать.

Comment: А у меня видели, сколько комментариев? Делайте выводы! :))

Comment: У вас хоть плюсик, значит, одобрили. ;) И вы тоже можете что-то сказать и про своё, и про моё.

Comment: Товарищи отвечающие! Что же вы все так скупы на плюсики? Отвечаете на вопрос и не отмечаете его. Римма, держите!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: я дал плюсик, а потом обиделся)) вернул)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Спасибо, Саша (щедрый вы наш!), за поддержку.

Comment: Ну и что скажете?

Answer (score 4):

А меня смущает *не должен.* Не должен кому? Вот если бы *не **мог** потерпеть* — тогда другое дело. И ещё мне хочется заменить *потерпеть* на *вынести:*

*Такого унижения он не мог вынести.*

*Потерпеть* не скажу, чтобы совсем не подходило. Теперь, кажется, понял про *не должен был:* ему следовало воспротестовать против него, а он его безропотно снёс, да?

Всё, теперь понял! Можно я не буду стирать ход своих мыслей? Действительно, *терпеть* лучше, мне кажется, глагол несовершенного вида тут больше подходит.

Теперь насчёт падежа. *Терпеть* в этом значении (мириться) действительно сочетается с винительным падежом. ***Но*** у нас есть отрицание, поэтому я бы не менял *родительного падежа.*

Comment: Не мог вынести — совершенно иной смысл от того предложения, что в вопросе. У слова ‟должен” десятки значений, и почти все они не требуют того, чтобы был кто-то, кому должны.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой О-и!.. Сколько же я огребла  за не столь долгий кусочек времени! Задала вопрос. Сразу дернули по делам. Отплыла, чегой-то порешала. Вернулась...  Вот она я. Без обид — спасибо всем, "щаз" все просмотрю, нарисую, поправлю...

Comment: Ура, Римма! Простите, если что!)

Comment: «Должен» — это не глагол, а краткое прилагательное.

Answer (score 1):

Заменим на другое слово:
*Такого поражения он не должен был потерпеть.* || Но потерпел. Тут вроде бы порядок.

Какая сочетаемость у "потерпел унижение"? Что-то оно не сочетается, но в исходном предложении звучит лучше из-за расстояния между словами (расстояние сглаживает несочетаемость или плохую сочетаемость).

"Не должен" указывает на малую вероятность того, что произошло.

Answer (score 1):

Более лучший вариант: ‟Он не должен был подвергнуться такому унижению”.
Скорее всего, вас смутил глагол ‟потерпеть”, который не используется, когда кто-то подвергается страданиям выше среднего, или даже низкого, уровня.

Comment: Насчёт **более лучший** есть такой [любопытный материал](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/28_14).

Comment: Более лучший = за пределами наилучшего, за гранью максимально возможного качества.

Comment: Я догадался. По ссылке выше как раз объясняется, почему носитель русского языка свободно понимает даже такие конструкции. (Мне нравится Ваша скромность: всё же Вы не сочли свой ответ **наиболее наилучшим** :)

Comment: За гранью максимально возможного качества уже ничего быть не может. На то оно и максимальное.

Comment: Это поэтически-философское фигуральное значение о преодолении непреодолимых рубежей.

Comment: Более лучший вариант = вариант получше (так корректно). За пределами наилучшего = более чем лучший.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол потерпеть просит устойчивого словосочетания с поражением, а унижение вызывает здесь удивление. Если же унижение здесь инвариантно, то, конечно, стерпеть.